# Git: git checkout with modified working tree and index

Tags: git

I expect `git checkout <commit>` to flash both the working tree and index to the `<commit>` version. However, in some cases it will keep the current changes in both the working tree and index. For example:

```
git branch br1
git branch br2
git checkout br1
<make change M1 to file foo>
git add foo
<make change M2 to file foo>
git checkout br2
```

Now all the working tree/index changes made in branch `br1` are kept in the branch `br2`, as `git status` on `br2` won't give a clean message. I guess this is because the head of `br1` and `br2` originally have the same version of file `foo`, and Git can automatically detect this.

Question:

- When does Git decide not to flash the working tree and index? Are there any other corner cases?

Comment: This isn't a corner case, the idea is that you may decide that before committing that you want to commit on a new branch. So long as the switch from one branch to another won't overwrite any modified files/cause issues for the index git will simply switch over to the branch.

Comment: @X-Istence But how does git decide **it won't cause issues**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `git checkout` command actually has two different (common) operating modes.

1. If you run `git checkout <branch>`, then you will switch to branch `<branch>`.  All changes to the working tree will be kept -- and this works by merging the uncommitted changes to the target branch, so it can fail.  Changes in the index will be stashed.
2. If you run `git checkout <path>`, then git will wipe out the changes to `<path>` in both the index and the working copy by getting them from the current commit.

So the purpose of `git checkout <branch>` is in case you decide that the changes you're making actually belong on a different branch.